# LINQ Query is not displaying mt data in my Google chart (Report)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, charts

I have a LINQ query which gets the `Type` and count of types, and I have it in my controller.  In my view I am using a Pie Chart from Google Charts and I am trying to display the data acquired by the LINQ statement. However, when I run the program the Pie Chart doesn't display.  No errors appear though.  So I am struggling to see whether my problem is my View or the Controller

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Report_5()
{                
     return View();
}

public ActionResult GetChart5()
{
    var result = from x in db.Submission
                 group x by x.Type into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     Type = grp.Key,
                     Count = grp.Count()
                 };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Report_5 View:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">Type Count</h2>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>                   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Count');

        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetChart5")", null, function (chartData) {
            $.each(chartData, function (i, item) {
                data.addRow([item.Type, item.Count]);
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    }
</script>                    

<div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: can you please give some sample of data which goes into result? Some kind of array, list, etc?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2zmle52stc6alf/Sample.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Your errors are related to java script code, not to C# code. In order to see java script errors, you should use some debugging features of browsers. For example in chrome you can press F12 in order to call debug window and find there needed for your error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following:
1. created view in folder Models.

```
public class ModelSubmission
{
    public string  Type { get; set; }
    public int TotalSubmissions { get; set; }
}
```

2. In home controller created the following:

   public ActionResult Report_5()
       {
           return View();
       }

   ```
   public ActionResult GetChart5()
   {
       List<ModelSubmission> result = new List<ModelSubmission>();
       result.Add(new ModelSubmission() { Type="Book", TotalSubmissions = 3 });
       result.Add(new ModelSubmission() { Type = "Book chapter", TotalSubmissions = 7 });
       result.Add(new ModelSubmission() { Type = "Journal Article", TotalSubmissions = 3 });

       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

And then copy/pasted your view. Then executed for debugging, and as you mentioned seen nothing special. After clicking F12 in chrome I noticed following error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: drawChart is not defined.
It lead me to conclusion, that in your code instead of

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

you should write

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
```

After some debugging I noticed other errors in your code. Try to find them while watching the following view:

```
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Type Count</h2>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script      src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js">     </script>
 <script      src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

     function drawTable() {
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

         data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

         $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetChart5")", null, function (chartData) {
             $.each(chartData, function (i, item) {
                 data.addRow([item.Type, item.TotalSubmissions]);
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        var options = {
            'title': 'Forgotten input',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
        };
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

You should be more careful when [copy/paste](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) code from other pages